# Rake task to assign default values to hash throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a serialized attribute preferences inside the model User which looks like this :

```
user.preferences
=> 
 @allow_fans=true,
 @approvals={:email=>true, :message=>false},
 @comment_on_an_item={:email=>false, :message=>true},
 @community_invitations={:email=>true, :message=>true},
 @community_requests={:email=>true, :message=>true},
 @flags={:email=>true, :message=>true},
 @follows={:email=>false, :message=>true},
 @likes_and_shares={:email=>false, :message=>true},
 @make_my_email_visible=true,
 @trackbacks_pingbacks={:email=>true, :message=>false}>
```

I have written a rake task to assign default preferences hash to existing users like below

```
namespace :user_preferences do
  desc "set default preferences for existing users"
  task :pref_defaults => :environment do
    default = {:comment_on_an_item => {'email' => nil, 'message' => true},
      :likes_and_shares => {'email' => nil, 'message' => true},
      :flags => {'email' => true, 'message' => true},
      :trackbacks_pingbacks => {'email' => true, 'message' => nil},
      :community_invitations => {'email' => true, 'message' => true},
      :approvals => {'email' => nil, 'message' => true},
      :community_requests => {'email' => true, 'message' => true},
      :follows => {'email' => nil, 'message' => true}}

    User.update_all(:preferences => default)
  end
end
```

But when I run the rake task `rake user_preferences:pref_defaults`, I get the error

```
** Invoke user_preferences:pref_defaults (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute user_preferences:pref_defaults
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'---
- :likes_and_shares
- email: 
  message: true
'"
LINE 5: ','---
          ^
: UPDATE "users" SET "preferences" = '---
- :comment_on_an_item
- email: 
  message: true
','---
- :likes_and_shares
- email: 
  message: true
','---
- :flags
- email: true
  message: true
','---
- :trackbacks_pingbacks
- email: true
  message: 
','---
- :community_invitations
- email: true
  message: true
','---
- :approvals
- email: 
  message: true
','---
- :community_requests
- email: true
  message: true
','---
- :follows
- email: 
  message: true
'
```

Kindly help me to get through this error.

Answer (score 1):

see comments here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

> If you use update_all to change an attribute marked as serialized (
>   using ActiveRecord::Base.serialize ), you need to call `to_yaml`
>   yourself:

```
User.update_all({ :preferences => { :first_name => ‘John’, :last_name  => 'Doe' }.to_yaml })
```